# How does hunting instinct work?

Tags: jurassic-world-evolution

I had an enclosure going with a Triceretops and some other small, cheap herbivores. At some point I got a contract to hatch a carnivore, so I figured, why not introduce a Ceratosaurus in the habitat? I figured I'd have to occasionally replace a herbivore to keep the flock going, but otherwise did not expect what happened.

The Ceratosaurus has now butchered its way through roughly 20 dinosaurs, and does not seem to consider giving up its career as a psychopathic murder machine anytime soon.

I do have a live bait feeder as well, which claims it'll "help satisfy Dinosaur hunting needs", but it doesn't really seem like the dinosaurs even have a hunting need, they just kill everything they come across.

So is there actually a "hunting instinct"? Or are the dinosaurs just programmed to kill everything they come across, hunger be damned?

Answer (score 1):

Carnivores will kill herbivores as their highest priority, regardless of whether they're hungry or not.